# Get result from MotorEngine async query

Tags: python, tornado, tornado-motor

I'm trying to switch MongoEngine with MotorEngine in my Tornado app for the sake of asynchronous DB access and so far I got nowhere.

`query`

```
@gen.coroutine
    def get_all_users(self):
        users = yield User.objects.find_all()
```

`handler`

```
class IUser(BaseHandler):
    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self,userId=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            userMethods = UserMethods()
            sessionId = self.request.headers.get('sessionId')
            ret = userMethods.get_all_users()
        except Exception as ex:
            print str(ex)

        self.finish()
```

When I print `ret` variable it says `<tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7fb0236fe450>`. If I try to print `ret.result()` it gets me nowhere.

Any help is appreciated since I'm struggling with everything I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_all_users needs to return its value somehow. In Python 2.6 or 2.7, generators aren't allowed to use the "return" statement, so coroutines have a special "Return" exception:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get_all_users(self):
    users = yield User.objects.find_all()
    raise gen.Return(users)
```

In Python 3.3 and later, you can simply "return users".

Now in "get", calling "get_all_users" only gives you a pending Future, not a value. You must wait for the Future to resolve to a value by yielding it:

```
ret = yield userMethods.get_all_users()
```

For more about calling coroutines from coroutines, see my ["Refactoring Tornado Coroutines"](http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).

By the way, you can decorate "get" with just "gen.coroutine", it's more modern than "asynchronous" and "gen.engine", but either style works.

Comment: A+ answer, like always. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. If you want to avoid to create an instance of userMethods every time you use its method:

```
userMethods = UserMethods()
```

You can use the `@classmethod` decorator before declaring it:

```
class UserMethods():
    pass

@classmethod
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def get_all_users(self):
    users = yield User.objects.find_all()
    raise gen.Return(users)

## class IUser
...

try:
    # userMethods = UserMethods()   --not necesary now--
    sessionId = self.request.headers.get('sessionId')
    ret = yield userMethods.get_all_users()
except Exception as ex:
    print str(ex)
...
```